# Wordpress top banner to add random post

Tags: wordpress

I am thinking of adding a small full width and 200px height a div which contain some random post(it will be just random choosen by wordpress), done by me with image and a small <20 words post title.
How can i do this, is there any plugin for it.

After researching and trying i am not getting anything.
Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to widget menu..

2) Add the widget to the home sidebar
http://wordpress.org/plugins/spider-random-post/

3) Edit the index.php code and call the home sidebar to header.php file. (It will remain on all pages).
 edit the code and css as per your requirement.